# how to point to a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

So I have a shared_ptr in my Main class, and I'd like some other object (a singleton class) to have access to what the shared_ptr is pointing to.

In pseudo code...

```
mySingletonInstance->somePointer = myShared_ptr;
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe, `mySingletonInstance->somePointer = &(*myShared_ptr)`

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko but somePointer can be a simple pointer or it must be a shared_ptr too?

Comment: @ildjarn so somePointer would be a weak_ptr?

Comment: @Pier : Assuming you don't want the singleton to keep the object alive indefinitely (i.e. share ownership), yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the singleton should participate in shared management of the object that is held by shared_ptr then it's somePointer could be simply a copy of that shared_ptr. Otherwise use a weak_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `mySingletonInstance->somePointer` to respect the ownership semantics of `shared_ptr`, then:

```
class MySingletonClass {
    SomeType* somePointer;
}
shared_ptr<SomeType> myShared_ptr;
...
// Then either of the following lines:
mySingletonInstance->somePointer = mySharedPtr.get();
mySingletonInstance->somePointer = &*mySharedPtr;
```

But beware -- your `somePointer` might hold a pointer to the object even after it has been deleted.

Comment: I don't see this as an improvement on `weak_ptr<>`, since this presents the opportunity to dereference a deleted object.

Comment: @ildjarn - The only advantage of this over `weak_ptr<>` is not having to call `weak_ptr::lock()`.